# Is there any way to tell Windows to hibernate, and then reboot, not hibernate, then shut down?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, hibernate

> Is there any way to tell Windows to hibernate, and then reboot, not hibernate, then shut down?

Why do I want it. I have dual boot ubuntu18.04/win7 on a 2008-year machine. Windows runs rather slow there but we use it for gaming mostly, while ubuntu is used for docker, programming, etc and it's rather fast.

Windows shuts down about 6-10 minutes, so I want to use hibernate to switch OSes. Is there any way I can do it? API calls or batch cmd scripts will be fine too.

I assume not. Because windows is designed to be the only OS on a machine, so there's no point in rebooting after hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: If you hibernate on an NTFS partition it will be only be mountable as read-only in linux. If you "fix" it in linux to make it writable again you will likely break the hibernation state & windows will cold boot.

Comment: Also *"Windows shuts down about 6-10 minutes"* -- That's a *very* long time for shutdown. You probably have a process or service that is experiencing some major issues and blocking the shutdown until it finally exits. Fix that issue and you may not need to hibernate.

Comment: @Romen thanks. How do I examine shutdown logs or something for finding this out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. try this in the cmd:

```
shutdown /h
```

If you want it to hibernate automatically on shutting down, type this in the cmd:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate on
```

Comment: Please see the edits on the question

Answer (score 0):

You *can* switch from Windows OS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS OS *even if Windows is in hibernation*. However, that would leave the Windows partition in a "dirty" state, with *hiberfil.sys* still present. Because of that, Ubuntu will mount the Windows partition in *read-only* mode, to prevent damage to that partition. Data can be accessed, and Windows programs can be run using *wine*, but data cannot be safely written. (It *is* [possible to *force* Ubuntu to mount it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition) with *write* permission... at the risk of making Windows unbootable).

To get around this issue, I use two scripts to shut Windows. When planning to open in Windows again, or in Ubuntu without needing to *write* to the NTFS partition, the first script *enables* hibernation, then hibernates:

```
powercfg -h on
shutdown /h
```

When planning to boot to Ubuntu, the following disablee hibernation and performs a full shutdown.

```
powercfg -h off
shutdown /s /t 0
```

Make shortcuts to the two .bat scripts, and in the *Advanced* Properties of the ,lnk file, set it to *Run as administrator*.

So, most of the time, you have the short delay of resuming from hibernation; but after having booted Ubuntu with *write* access, yes, there is that interminable delay (well, seven minutes until you see the login screen, and a few more minutes until it's up-to-speed, having finished the preliminary virus scan after boot).

Comment: Thanks. `shutdown /h` does exactly 'hibernates then _shut down_' while the question is how to 'hubernate then _reboot_', sorry it wasn't so clear the first time.

Comment: A full reboot leaves the hiberfil.sys invalid, and, as you state, takes about 7 minutes, so there's no point in doing so after hibernating. And you *can* quickly resume from hibernation, even after using Ubuntu, if you have not opened the Windows partition to write.

Comment: Sure, but doesn't `shutdown /h` switch computer's power off? I have to switch the system back on, that's the point of the question. I want to be able to boot into ubuntu just after hiberhate, not having to turn the power back on. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! I didn't understand that. And, as you suspect, I know of no way to hibernate and *then* immediately restart... once it's hibernated, the machine is completely off.